# Redactor no longer maintained

Tags: redactor, craft4, craft5, alternative

What is a recommended alternative to the redactor plugin?
Or just use it anyway?

Cheers, Joe

Comment: Is CKEditor Plugin a valid alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CKEditor plugin, which is also a first-party plugin by Pixel & Tonic.

https://plugins.craftcms.com/ckeditor

The Craft 5 version allows for embedding other entries as part of a long form content feature. I did an overview here: https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-5-guide/180563